# Create a list of object usable in more activity

Tags: android, arrays, list, object, storage

I want to create a list of object that is accessible by more activity.
I thought to create a class with the list of object (not array). I used this...

```
public class List{
    Object object1 = new Object("this", 59, true)
    ...
   }
```

And activity

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        ...
       ArrayList<Object> array = new ArrayList<>();
       array.add(Object(List.object1));
       ...}}
```

in List.object1 there's the error method call expected.

There's a easier method to storage the objects and more efficient?

Comment: You can extend the Application class and create a create a global list of objects that you can access anywhere in your application

Comment: @NollyJ If this is what the OP is after.  Frankly, I'm not very clear about what the OP wants/needs.  Maybe it's just creating a list of objects in one activity and make it accessible to another activity.

Comment: Yes, it is not clear but I based my intuition on this part of statement - "by more activity"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will base this solution that you want to create a list of objects and use it in different activity class.

**First solution** - You can create a custom application class and instantiate your list of object in the onCreate callback method. This is give you access to your list of object in other class

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application {

private List<YourClassName> listOfObjects;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    listOfObjects = new ArrayList<YourClassName>();
}

private List<YourClassName> getListOfObject(){
    return listOfObjects;
}
}
```

Then to access it, you can use this line of code

```
List<YourClassName> objectList = ((CustomApplication)getApplication()).getListOfObject();
```

**Second solution** - You can use a Wrapper class to wrap your list of objects like below.

Assuming you have this User class

```
public class User {
private String name;
private String email;
private String username;


public User(String name, String email, String username) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.username = username;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
}
```

then the Wrapper class will look like this

```
public class Wrapper {
private List<User> users;

public Wrapper(List<User> users){
    this.users = users;
}

public List<User> getUsers(){
    return  users;
}
}
```

You can convert your Wrapper class to a Json String

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(Wrapper);
```

You can store you jsonString in a sharepreference like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("IDENTIFIER", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edits = prefs.edit();
edits.putString("LIST_OBJECT", jsonString);
edits.apply();
```

To get back the list of User in a class, you will use the code below. Get the json string in sharedpreference like this

```
String jListObject = prefs.getString("LIST_OBJECT", "")
```

then get list of User objects

```
Wrapper listObjectWrapper = gson.fromJson(stringObject, Wrapper.class);
List<User> users = listObjectWrapper.getUsers();
```

**Third solution** - you can use the TypeToken to convert json string to list of object like the example below

Create a list of User objects

```
List<User> objList = new ArrayList<User>();
objList.add(new User("high", "zero.yahoo.com", "zero"));
objList.add(new User("low", "one.yahoo.com", "one"));
```

convert the list object to string

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(objList);
```

Store the json string in a sharedpreference using the example in second solution

When you retrieve the json string, you can reconvert it to object list of User as shown below

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<DataObject>>(){}.getType();
List<DataObject> inpList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

Remember to add this line in your app build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```

Comment: Thanks, is possible to search inside the objects? Like only name, only username or both (excluding email)?

Comment: Yes, after this line List<User> users = listObjectWrapper.getUsers(); you now have your list of objects. To get an object or all the objects in the list, you can loop the list of users for(User singleUser : users){ singleUser.getName()}; will return a name.

Answer (score 0):

you can store your data in settings like this:
settingsservice:

```
public class SettingsService {
    private static String KEY = Constants.SETTINGS_KEY;
    private static Context mContext;

    public static SettingsModel settings;

    public SettingsService(){
        mContext = YourApplicationClass.getApplicationContext();
        if(settings == null){
            settings = getSettings();
        }
    }

    public static void saveSettings(SettingsModel settings){
        if(settings != null){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext
                    .getSharedPreferences(KEY, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            SettingsService.settings = settings;
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonSettings = gson.toJson(settings);
            editor.putString("settings", jsonSettings );
            editor.commit();
        }
    }

    public static void saveSettings(){
        if(settings == null){
            settings = new SettingsModel();
        }
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext
                .getSharedPreferences(KEY, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonSettings = gson.toJson(settings);
        editor.putString("settings", jsonSettings );
        editor.commit();
    }


    private static SettingsModel getSettings() {
        SharedPreferences editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences(KEY,
                Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        try{
            String jsonSettings = editor.getString("settings","settings");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            settings = gson.fromJson(jsonSettings, SettingsModel.class);
        }catch (Exception e){
            settings = new SettingsModel();
        }

        return settings;
    }
}
```

create settings model whatever objects you want inside:

```
public class SettingsModel {
    public String email;
    public String password;
    // anything you need else
}
```

then from anywhere in your codes:

```
SettingsService.settings.email = "your email";
SettingsService.saveSettings();
```

also from anywhere in your code:

```
String myEmail = SettingsService.settings.email;
```

also make sure you have in your gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```